# My HTML5 webpage is not being read correctly in IE 9

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9

Hello my website http://www.paruhdice.com/index2.html is not acting as it should be. It worked some what fine in IE 8. And works perfectly in the latest CHROME and Firefox... but my sliding navigation is not even responding. What should I do? Prompt users to use CHROME or FIREFOX... or is there a fix to this? Thanks ahead of time

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be working for me in IE 9.0.8112.16421 as well as the latest Firefox release.  The left-hand navigation bar moves smoothly with the window as I re-size.

Comment: Thanks so much...maybe cuz my version was a fresh install and I had not restarted my computer....but thanks...... wish i can up this..for your help.. don't have 15 rep points yet... but when I do I will..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, HTML5 is not a fully implemented standard, so you won't get full support in any browser. IE9 was also released back in march and both Chrome and Firefox have made great strides since then to add more support for HTML5.  Doing a quick web search I came up with the site, http://html5test.com/results.html. It certainly gives an interesting overview of your current browsers support for html5 as well as the ranking of other browsers by comparison.

Since it all ready sounds like you are telling all of the old IE, Safari, Firefox users to update to view your site, I see no reason to tell them some features don't work and you recommend they upgrade.

Comment: IE9 is the first version of Internet Explorer to support HTML5. No browser supports it fully of course.

Comment: That is what I'm trying to say, is that there are degrees of support for each browser.  Even though IE9 was the first IE to support some HTML5 features, IE just isn't as up-to-date as Chrome and Firefox are. So it's good to make sure what each browser is capable of using before you implement that feature of HTML5 because it's not a fully implemented by any browser.  Hopefully by IE10 we won't have to worry about HTML5 feature implementation, but until that day, it's good to know what browsers support what.

Comment: thanks thanks thanks.. think i am going to add a PROMPT for users to upgrade.. ....THANK you all for paying me some attention.. GREAT community here..